# Java - Problems with reading from process output

Tags: java, process

My OS is Windows 8.1 64 bit
I need to read process output, but if it works more than 5 hours, I should destroy the process. So, there are two ways: 1) process works < 5 hours and it ends by itself; 2) it if works >= 5 hours, after that time I destroy it. I had two variants:

1.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(corePath.getAbsolutePath(), ... );
Process core = pb.start();
if(!core.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.HOURS))
{
    System.out.println("Process destroyed, path " + root.getAbsolutePath());
    core.destroy();
}
String output = IOUtils.toString(core.getInputStream());
return output;
```

2.

```
Process core = pb.start();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(core.getInputStream()));
String line;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end && (line = input.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line);
}
input.close();
```

Problems:
1) program was waiting exactly 5 hours (even if process should be finished in few seconds)
2) program is waiting until the process is end

May someone advise another way to handle this? Thanks

Comment: Chances are you need to do a bit of both: you need to have a thread that reads the standard output of the process (you can throw away the contents) and you need a thread that waits for the process to finish or 5 hours using `Process.waitFor()`. The reason for this is that with 1 the process might block, waiting for you to read out its output buffer, while with 2 your application will block, waiting indefinitely in `input.readLine()` until it outputs a line.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be with the `BufferedReader`. Are you trying to use the `BufferedReader` to get inptut? If so, use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: I could solve a deadlock because of BufferedReader.readLine or InputStreamReader.read blocking forever after the underlying process has been destroyed by reading with `while(process.isAlive()) {while(scanner.hasNext()) {String line = scanner.nextLine();}}` on different threads for both stdout and stderr.